# Alguien ha consumido un servicio web de Cast Iron en PHP?

Tags: php

Tengo un servicio web desarrollado en Cast Iron de IBM que solo envia como respuesta un XML de una Consulta pero no se como consumirlo en PHP

Comment: Revisa [ask] ..

Answer (score 0):

Pude resolverlo, todo fue desde CastIron me faltaba un archivo WSDL comparto la solución para obtener el servicio web desde PHP con una libreria:nuSoap/lib/nusoap.php

```
<?require_once('nuSoap/lib/nusoap.php');

$cliente1 = new nusoap_client("http://tuiponombredehost/elnombredetuorquestacion",false);

$parametros1=array('proc'=>'ok'); //parametros de la llamada
$respuesta1 = $cliente1->call("EnviarS",$parametros1);//EnviarS es un parametro que se configura en mi WSDL

foreach($respuesta1 as $rr){
                $nombre = $rr;
                echo '<br>';
               print_r ($nombre);
}
?>
```